# How to use opencv snake function in Java?

Tags: java, opencv

> I want to use Snake function in my java code,but i can't find it in Java's OpenCV document.
>   I've saw [cvSnakeImage](https://gist.github.com/mrgloom/2101cef88005987e9870) in C++ but i can't find the Java function.

Comment: We are not here to code it for you, please show something that you've done and are stuck with a problem, then anyone on SO would be happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvSnakeImage` has been deprecated for awhile now. It was first moved to the *legacy* modules thereafter OpenCV just got rid of *legacy* altogether.

You could try re-implementing should you wish. The core algorithm is something along the lines of:

```
while(!converged)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < number_of_points; ++index)
    {
        Calculate Econt
        Calculate Ecurv
        Calculate Eimg
        ENERGY = alpha * Econt + beta * Ecurv + gamma * Eimg;
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://eric-yuan.me/active-contour-snakes/).

Depending on your application, try exploring [`convexHull`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html) and [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html)

**Edit I**

Read [this](https://mat-web.upc.edu/people/toni.susin/files/SnakesAivru86c.pdf) paper for more info on the snake algorithm

**Edit II**

After digging around, I found that their source code still lives in their [2.4 branch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/legacy/src/snakes.cpp). You can go ahead and re-write it in Java should you still wish to. Or just installing OpenCV 2.4 and see if you can access the implementation.